# Can't print the dojo enhanced grid

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I have an enhanced grid and activated the "Printer" plugin. Also, I've made a dijit/button and connected it to an onClick event, which calls a print method. The event is fired so there is no problem. The problem is, that it doesn't work. I get following message in the opera console:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'str' to object

Error thrown at line 511, column 21 in <anonymous function: trim>(str) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojo/_base/lang.js:
return str.trim();
called from line 131, column 3 in <anonymous function: _loadCSSFiles>(cssFile) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
cssFile = lang.trim(cssFile);
called from line 282, column 5 in <anonymous function: map>(arr, callback, thisObject, Ctr) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojo/_base/array.js:
out[i] = callback(arr[i], i, arr);
called from line 130, column 2 in <anonymous function: _loadCSSFiles>(cssFiles) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
var dl = array.map(cssFiles, function(cssFile){
called from line 226, column 2 in <anonymous function: _wrapHTML>(title, cssFiles, body_content) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
return this._loadCSSFiles(cssFiles).then(function(cssStrs){
called from line 125, column 3 in <anonymous function: exportSelectedToHTML>(str) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
_this._wrapHTML(args.title, args.cssFiles, args.titleInBody + str).then(onExported);
called from line 128, column 2 in <anonymous function: exportSelected>(type, writerArgs, onExported) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Exporter.js:
return onExported(this._goThroughGridData(this.grid.selection.getSelected(), writer));
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 375, column 68 in <anonymous function: hitch>() in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojo/_base/lang.js:
return method.apply(scope, arguments || []);
called from line 124, column 2 in <anonymous function: exportSelectedToHTML>(args, onExported) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
this.grid.exportSelected("table", args.writerArgs, function(str){
called from line 94, column 2 in <anonymous function: printSelected>(args) in http://localhost/ci/assets/js/dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Printer.js:
this.exportSelectedToHTML(args, lang.hitch(this, this._print));
```

Here is the code for the event:

```
                require([
                    "dijit/registry"
                ],function(registry) {
                    var grid = registry.byId('grid');
                    grid.printSelected({
                        "title": "test"
                    });
                });
```

Has somebody an idea what I can do, to get this plugin at work? 
PS: I've also tried to print with Google Chrome, but neither this is working... .

Comment: I've just found out, that it might have something to do with the content of the table.
I have a button widget in every row of the table. Can this course the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like there has to be the "cssFiles" property. After I inserted it, everything worked. (Opera made a little bit of a problem, but nothing to worry about... )